# different hovers on individual paths/polygons in svg

Tags: html, css, svg

I access the svg via js.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            $(function(){

    $("#stage").load('img/europa_regionen.svg',function(response){

        $(this).addClass("svgLoaded");

        if(!response){
            // Error loading SVG!
            // Make absolutely sure you are running this on a web server or localhost!
        }

    });
});

    </script>
```

I manage to change the color of an individual polygon inside one svg in my css:

```
[id$=_x3C_object_x3E_] {
    fill: #ffffff;
}
```

Is there any way to ad a hover-effect to that id in my css, so that the color of the fill changes on mouse-over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with `:hover` ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaer/azw646ka/)):

```
[id$=_x3C_object_x3E_]:hover {
  fill: red;
  stroke: blue;
}
```

Comment: Do you by any chance know if it's possible to ad links to the individual ids/polygons in a svg? Thank you so much!

Comment: You can add anchor elements inside your svg, like this: https://jsfiddle.net/ivanchaer/7vq0wbou/

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant. I have several polygons inside the svg, each with it's own id. They now hover perfectly, like you showed me. I don't know how to address the individual ids in the html to give it a link. I don't know if that's even possible without js.

Comment: Just found the answer myself. Inside the svg add <a xlink:href="#"></a> around individual paths/polygons.